# How to read data from table in Azure on Windows Phone 8

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8

It's Windows Phone 8 (Azure) application. I try to get whole table PicturesTable to PictureList. But I have only empty rows (the number of rows is the same that in Azure Database, so it synchronize corretly but without values).

```
public class PicturesTableItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

}

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private MobileServiceCollectionView<PicturesTableItem> PicturesItems;
    private IMobileServiceTable<PicturesTableItem> PicturesTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<PicturesTableItem>();
    private List<PicturesTableItem> PictureList = new List<PicturesTableItem>();

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    private void RefreshPicturesTableItems()
    {
        PicturesItems = PicturesTable.ToCollectionView();
    }

    /*
     * Override
     */
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshPicturesTableItems();
    }
}
```

I want to show it in this way

```
string temp = "";
foreach (var element in PictureList)
{
    temp = temp + element.Address.ToString()+"\n";
}
MessageBox.Show(temp.ToString());
```

Can you told me how to do it in good way?

I can't go

```
PictureList = PicturesTable.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I try to make something like that - PictureList = await App.MobileService.GetTable<PicturesTableItem>().ToListAsync(); with private async Task but it won't work as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that **column** name in database is the same as `DataMember` name. In my case this was solution for this same problem.

Comment: i'll check this after I get home

Comment: Working fine. I deleted [DataMember] and now I don't have null strings. Thank you!